# Pubg Mobile Api - Is there any way to log in with PUBG Mobile account to my mobile app

Tags: node.js, react-native, api, authentication, logging

I am developing a mobile app for find duos or teams for PUBG Mobile and League of Legends in Lol user can log in with his/her account to my app with third party code. But I can not find any information about PUBG Mobile third party code or third party log in. Is there any technology or api exist for this problem ?

Comment: If your Query is answered then consider upvoting/accepting the answer at it may help others in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think there is any such service provided by PUBG mobile. If it was it should be available on their official site.